# Datatable server side wordpress integration

Tags: wordpress, datatables, server-side

So, I am inheriting an intranet site that was built on datatables. Basically it is made in Wordpress and then displays custom fields that the users have filled out in the datatable. But it was querying 40 columns per post over 2k entries so is now grinding to a standstill when the users try and view the data in the table.

I'm attempting to utilize the server-side aspect of Datatables for this, but running into a little trouble because of how the sql data is formatted.

Can anyone offer any assistance in how to set up the server_processing.php file (i'm using this one: http://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql) to:

1. Display rows based on the wp_posts.ID index
2. Display columns in this row based on a different table (wp_postmeta) wherein each column value is indexed separately in the wp_postmeta table by the ID found in 1
3. Link entire row to a url found in the wp_posts table

If anyone has any ideas I would really appreciate it...

Comment: i'm actually really unsure where to start, so i haven't really tried too much. The ajax file i'm using is this: http://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql though

Answer (score 0):

Probably you might be interested in this plugin - looks like it does exactly what you're looking for: http://wpdatatables.com

An example with server-side processing: http://wpdatatables.com/display-mysql-table-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely need a Wordpress table plugin that wraps DataTables functionality. You may consider Tabulizer for Wordpress (http://www.tabulizer.com) that supports server side processing and loads table data via Ajax calls only when needed. There is also a data source cache for improved performance.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax dataTable  or server-side processing dataTable in WordPress or Core PHP.

> **HTML Code**

```
<table id="student_table" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Roll No.</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Roll No.</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

> **jQuery code**

```
jQuery('#student_table').DataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax":{
        "url": FrontendConfig.ajaxurl+'?action=getStudentsFromExamIdAjax&exam_nounce=exam_nounce_data&exam_id=1',
        type: "post",
    }
});
```

> **WordPress or PHP code**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_getStudentsFromExamIdAjax', 'getStudentsFromExamIdAjax' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getStudentsFromExamIdAjax', 'getStudentsFromExamIdAjax' );

function getStudentsFromExamIdAjax(){
    if(empty($_GET['action']) || empty($_GET['exam_id'])){
        wp_send_json_error( new \WP_Error( 'Bad Request' ) );
    }

    if(isset($_GET['exam_id']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && wp_verify_nonce( $_GET['exam_nounce'], 'exam_nounce_data' )):

        $exam_id = (isset($_GET['exam_id'])) ? absint($_GET['exam_id']) : '';

        /*@ You can create a function to get the data here */
        $students = getStudentsFromExamId($exam_id);

        $tdata = [];
        foreach ($students as $key => $value):
            $tdata[$key][] = $value->roll_no;
            $tdata[$key][] = $value->name;
            $tdata[$key][] = $value->phone;
            $tdata[$key][] = 'action here';
        endforeach;

        $total_records = count($tdata);

        $json_data = array(

            /* $_REQUEST['draw'] comes from the datatable, you can print to ensure that */

            "draw"            => intval( $_REQUEST['draw'] ), 
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $total_records ),
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $total_records  ),
            "data"            => $tdata
        );

        echo json_encode($json_data);
    endif;

    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: I have a question to your code. Here is my thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71193075/how-to-set-an-ajax-url-in-wordpress-i-want-to-call-it-with-datatables I think its a rather easy question for you.

Answer (score -1):

**Custom.js**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
alert('test');
 jQuery('#employee_grid').DataTable({
          "bProcessing": true,
          "serverSide": true,              
          "ajax":{
             url :ajax_url_object.ajax_url+'?action=getStudentsFromExamIdAjax&exam_nounce=exam_nounce_data&exam_id=1', // json datasource
             type: "POST",  // type of method  ,GET/POST/DELETE
             error: function(){
               jQuery("#employee_grid_processing").css("display","none");
             }
           }
   });  });
```

> WordPress or PHP code

```
function theme_styles1()
```

{

```
$template_dir_uri =content_url();
$pluginurl =plugins_url();

//====================js
wp_enqueue_style( 'vpn-custom-style1','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css', true );

wp_enqueue_style( 'vpn-custom-boostrap1','https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css', true );

wp_enqueue_script( 'vpn-script11','https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'vpn-script21','https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js', true );

wp_enqueue_script( 'vpn_script31', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'js/custom.js', true );
```

//============ ajax url

```
$urls= array('ajax_url'=> admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                'site_url' => site_url()
                );
wp_localize_script( 'vpn_script31', 'ajax_url_object',$urls);
```

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles1',99 );

```
div class="wrap">   
    <h1>Service List</h1>
<div class="container">
    <table id="employee_grid" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Empid</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Empid</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

add_action('wp_ajax_getStudentsFromExamIdAjax', 'getStudentsFromExamIdAjax' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getStudentsFromExamIdAjax', 'getStudentsFromExamIdAjax' );

function getStudentsFromExamIdAjax(){

```
global $wp;

$servername = "localhost:3308";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "demo";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
$params = $columns = $totalRecords = $data = array();

$params = $_REQUEST;
// echo "<pre>";
// print_r($params);
// die;

//define index of column
$columns = array( 
    0 =>'id',
    1 =>'employee_name', 
    2 => 'employee_salary',
    3 => 'employee_age'
);

$where = $sqlTot = $sqlRec = "";

// check search value exist
if( !empty($params['search']['value']) ) {   
    $where .=" WHERE ";
    $where .=" ( employee_name LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";    
    $where .=" OR employee_salary LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";

    $where .=" OR employee_age LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' )";
}

// getting total number records without any search
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `employee` ";
$sqlTot .= $sql;
$sqlRec .= $sql;
//concatenate search sql if value exist
if(isset($where) && $where != '') {

    $sqlTot .= $where;
    $sqlRec .= $where;
}


$sqlRec .=  " ORDER BY ". $columns[$params['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$params['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$params['start']." ,".$params['length']." ";

$queryTot = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlTot) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));


$totalRecords = mysqli_num_rows($queryTot);

$queryRecords = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlRec) or die("error to fetch employees data");

//iterate on results row and create new index array of data
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($queryRecords) ) { 
    $data[] = $row;
}   

// echo "<pre>";
// print_r($data);
// die;

$json_data = array(
        "draw"            => intval( $params['draw'] ),   
        "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalRecords ),  
        "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalRecords),
        "data"            => $data   // total data array
        );

echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format
```

}

Comment: I used the above code but did not assign data in the data table.  Could you please help?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).